# Crystal Report Installation in Windows Server 2016

Tags: crystal-reports, windows-server-2016

How to install crystal report in Windows Server 2016 64bit? i tried a lot but still didn't succeed.

A screenshot of the error:

[image: Installation Error Screenshot]